# Trying to add easing effect to jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make an easing/fading effect on tabs through jQuery.  How would I add an easing effect to my existing code.  Also, how could I add two css classes so the background changes color along with the color itself?  Thank you.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var origColor = $("#links-top-contact a").css("color");

        $("#links-top-contact a").hover(function() {

            $(this).css({color:'blue'});

        },function() {

            $(this).css({color:origColor});

        });

    })
```

;
CSS

```
#links-top-contact a{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid blue;
    padding:-5px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    border-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;
    -khtml-border-radius:25px;
    background-color:red;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<br/><div id="links-top-contact"><a href="#">yo</a></div>
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/HBaVS/16/) is the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [jquery color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color)? [Here](http://desizntech.info/2009/06/playing-with-jquery-color-plugin-and-color-animation/) you can find an example of how it works.

I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBaVS/29/) so you can see it working.

In your example it will be something like this:

```
var origColor = $("#links-top-contact a").css("background-color");

$("#links-top-contact a").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: origColor
    }, 500)
});
```

Comment: your code is wrong, it does both animations on hover and none on leave. Also this queues up all animations so that it keeps on changing if you hover many times in a short time

Comment: Awesome thank you!  How could I have it stop though.  So, it acts on mouseOver and mouseOut?  Would I have to use the $.noop() variable?

Comment: JUST FIXED IT, check (jsfiddle too)

Comment: added `dequeue()` method to stop continuous easing on hover-blur over the link. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBaVS/36)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this jquery plugin. I think it is what you need.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/animate-to-class

Comment: Can I add two classes like $(this).css({color:'blue'}).animate({....}); Also, how do add plugins?  I've just used to full jQuery library download.

Comment: to use a plugin, you just have to inlcude it in the head of your html like the jquery library. But you have to include jquery first! yes you can do it like that `$(this).css({color:'blue'}).animate({....});` but `color:blue` will not be animated

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the background-color as well.

```
$(this).css({color:'blue',backgroundColor:'green'});
```

To make it easier you can use the css :hover pseudoselector to modify text/background color instead of doing so from jQuery.

For easing/fading take a look at jQuery's animate and fadeIn fadeOut: [jQuery Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

Comment: it is working, but you have to write `backgroundColor` http://jsfiddle.net/MANQZ/1/